# Sharing ScummVM saves between Linux/Raspberry Pi and Linux/x86_64

Tags: linux, the-secret-of-monkey-island, scummvm

I have some save files from playing ScummVM on a Raspberry Pi (specifically, for Monkey Island 1). When I copy the `~/.scummvm/monkey.s*` files from the RasPi to my x86_64 notebook, they show up in the save picker as `Invalid version` for the name (but, interestingly, the thumbnails are correct) and loading fails.

Is there a way to load these save files on x86_64?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ScummVM dev here.

Save files between different ports of ScummVM *should* be directly exchangable, with two caveats:

1. Make sure both ports are up-to-date. Occasionally, the save format for the engines change, and old versions will not be able to load saves made with a newer version.
2. Saves are usually gzip-compressed. But some ports on less powerful hardware have gzip not compiled in, so you can't load a gzip-compressed save there. The default builds for amd64 GNU/Linux should always have gzip enabled, though. So unless you built ScummVM yourself and explicitly disabled gzip compression, I doubt this is the issue here.

So please, double-check that your amd64 GNU/Linux systems is running a ScummVM version number >= the ScummVM version on your Raspberry Pi. Especially when you're using a ScummVM build from your distribution, it might be severly out of date. Grab one of our [official release binary packages](http://scummvm.org/downloads/#stable) when in doubt.

If the issue persists, please [file a bug report](http://scummvm.org/faq/#question.report-bugs) so this can be inspected properly. We might have messed up badly and broken save game compatibility between ports.

In either case, please consider contacting us directly next time you have a ScummVM-related question. We have a forum and an IRC channel (#scummvm on Freenode). The forum even exists mainly for user support; you are way more likely to find help there than here.

Comment: Indeed, upgrading to ScummVM 1.7.0 on my amd64 fixed the issue.